# Angular2-router: How to only change a parameter of a route?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to have the following routes in my application:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { 
       path: ':universityId', 
       component: UniversityComponent,
       children: [
           { path: 'info', component: UniversityInfoComponent },
           { path: 'courses/:status', component: CoursesByStatusComponent }
       ]
    }
]
```

Being on `/1/info` or `/1/courses/open` url, how do I change `:universityId` only from `UniversityComponent`?

Simple `router.navigate(['../', 2], {relativeTo: currentRoute })` won't do because it redirects to `/2`, losing all other information. Using `'../2/courses/open` is also not an option - I can be on any child route at that moment.
Best I could come up with is:

```
const urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
urlTree.root.children['primary'].segments[0].path = '2';
this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
```

but it's kind of ugly

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm interested to know too.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Why did you leave this unanswered? :)

Comment: @sabithpocker don't have that much time anymore :-/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer cool, good for you. Your answers are **VERY** useful. And you kind of answered every question I searched for :P

Comment: Glad to hear. I hope you enjoy Angular :)

Comment: @Krishnan no :) In case if we need to do so (turns out this is kind of rare), we manipulate segments directly as in example above

Comment: Could this perhaps be done with a couple of tuples and router data providers. Then switchmap to combine results into tuple. I gave hint as to how to do router data provider here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892392/router-data-resolver-loading-indicator-from-angular-4-can-it-be-replicated-in & here's tuple syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177003/angular-router-data-resolver-resolve-returning-tuple-explain-parentheses-expres

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple.
You can simply try to use 
this.router.navigate(["../2", "courses", "open"], {relativeTo: this.route});

(or)

this.router.navigate(["../2", "courses/open"], {relativeTo: this.route});

This will redirect you to ../2/courses/open.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to go along with my comment above about using Tuples: So replicate this pattern twice... This [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892392/router-data-resolver-loading-indicator-from-angular-4-can-it-be-replicated-in) how to integrate these classes into your project. 
So:

1. change **data-component-resolver.ts** to **parent-child-resolver.ts** for code in the link.
2. replace **data-component.ts** in the link with **parent-child.component.ts** below

---

### parent-child-resolver.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {Parent} from '../shared/model/parent';
import {Children} from '../shared/model/children';
import {ParentService} from '../providers/parent.service';

@Injectable()
export class parentChildResolver implements Resolve<[Parent,(Children[])>

  constructor(private parentService : ParentService) {}

  resolve(  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot
         ) : Observable<[Parent,(Children[])> 
  {
      return this.parentService.findParentById(route.params['id'])
        .switchMap(parent => 
            this.parentService.findChildrenForParent(parent.id),
              (parent, children) => [parent, children]
         );
  }
}
```

---

### parent-child.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Parent} from '../shared/model/parent';
import {Children} from '../shared/model/children';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-child',
    templateUrl: './parent-child.component.html'
})

export class ParentChildComponent implements OnInit{
  $parent: Observable<Parent>;
  $children: Observable<Children[]>;

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parent$ = this.route.data.map(data => data['key'][0]); //from router.config.ts
    this.children$ = this.route.data.map(data => data['key'][1]);
  }
}
```