# Get Data from Firebase In descending Order

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i need to get data from Firebase in descending order .

When the component loads for the first time it happens fine.

```
  fetchData(){
    return this.af.list('/path/path/',{
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'createdAt'
      }
    }).map(arr => {return arr.reverse();});
  }
```

The data from fetch ads is stored in a var and then displayed.

But now the problem is the var is modified at run time the user can update the var array , or delete or add to it .

And when ever any of these operations takes place the data is modified on the firebase db and that calls the fetch data again .

But then the reverse is again revesed rendering the whole thing use less.

By this i mean is after the first component load the var is 1,2,3,4.
But then when we add to var instead of becoming 1,2,3,4,5 it becomes 5,4,3,2,1.

This is very confusing but i a tried lot but not able to fix this.

**UPDATE**

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.display = this.route.snapshot.data['Auth'];

    if(this.display){
      this.showProgress = true;
      this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
      this.service.fetchData().subscribe((data) => {
        this.comments = data;
        this.showProgress = false;
      });
    } else {
      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((data) => {
        if (data) {
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
          this.user = data;
          this.service.fetchData().subscribe((res) => {
            this.comments = res;
            this.showProgress = false;
          });
        } else {
          this.comments = null;
        }
      });
```

This is what happens on run time rest all are the crud functions of angular2firebase that happens when we add update or delete

I tried using pipes for the same but then it causes problem when getting the index so i dropped the plan as it was getting too complex

```
add(){
    this.service.postComment(this.comment, this.user);
  }

  editComment(key:string,updatedComment:any){
    const index = ((this.page-1)*5)+i;
    const updated = this.comments[index];
    updated.comment  = comment;
    this.service.editComment(updated.$key,updated);
  }

  deleteComment(key:String){
   this.service.deleteComment(this.comments[index].$key);
  }
```

Comment: Can we see where you assign `fetchData()` to the value?

Comment: @SrAxi updated the ngOnint this is where it is fired

Comment: So the issue is that on init `this.comments` gets the list as you want it (reversed), but the second time it's getting it ordered?

Comment: Show me the code for this: *"But now the problem is the var is modified at run time the user can update the var array"*, please. I'm pretty sure the issue is in that logic.

Comment: what might be the error here ? its just plain firebase commands

Comment: Where is i coming from inside editComment?

Comment: Also have you tried looking at the data in the Firebase console before and after updates. Are the nodes getting overwritten so 1 becomes 5 etc on update. Or is it a case of something else during the reloading? and insert a do(console.log) into the subscribe chain maybe.

Comment: the nodes remain the same , just at the time of load it changes

Comment: Is it plausible that somehow you are getting double subscriptions? So you need to unsubscribe before re-subscribing perhaps? i.e. ngInit is only place you subscribe?

Comment: yes @JGFMK that is the only place i am subscribing i am not sure how its comming twice

Comment: @JGFMK but if you look at the code the subscribe is called twice but based on condition is that the reason ? but it is inside a if else block

Comment: I think you should definitely update your question to show that finding. I'm not sure why your getting the double subscription. Is this.route.snapshot.data['Auth'] asynchronous maybe? That's out of my realm of expertise. But it seems extremely probable that's the root of your problem. Others might not see the last few comments in out exchange.

Comment: that route is async but it dosnt call the angular fire , this is the 80% code rest are all vars

Comment: I'm wondering if you can somehow chain something like a do off the this.route.snapshot.data['Auth'] and put the whole if block inside.. It may be some type of similar syntactic sugar that's required. Router Data Resolvers maybe...

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer - At the end it points you to how to implement a Router Data Resolver..

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a typo here:

```
  editComment(key:string,updatedComment:any){
    this.service.editComment(updatedComment.$key, updatedComment); // I changed `updated` to `updatedComment`
  }
```

Another thing you could do, is following on your reverse custom pipe approach, and when you do that, remove `reverse()` from your `map()` in `fetchData()`.

**Reverse Pipe:**

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'reverse',
  pure: false
})
export class ReversePipe {
  transform (values) {
    if (values) {
      return values.reverse();
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Try declaring the mapped and reversed response as a `FirebaseListObservable<any[]>`.

```
 fetchData(){
    return this.af.list('/path/path/',{
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'createdAt'
      }
    }).map((array) => array.reverse()) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  }
```

Comment: i have tried the pipes approach but i fires too many times and also i renderer components using renderer 2 by fetching dynamic id thats dosen't work properly . and that not a typo i updated the question

Comment: one unusual behaviour i have noticed when i add a new comment the fetch data is called twice why ?

Comment: After your update now when i update the when i insert the reverse is called 3 times once on page load and twice after submit so it works but i delete it calls it only once so the reverse revse cancels each other

Answer (score 0):

Does this sort of overview help?

app-module.ts

```
import {firebaseConfig} from "../firebase.config";
@ngModule({
 imports: [
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

  ]

})
```

firebase.config.ts

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "<your api key>",
    authDomain: "....",
    databaseURL: "....",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};
```

my-component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} rrom '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2';
import {Data} from "../shared/model/data"; //insert your domain class here & in code

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   data: Data[];
   constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.db.list('data', {
            query: {
                orderByKey: true,
                limitToLast: 10
            }
        })
            .do(console.log)
            .subscribe(
                data => this.data = data
            );
    }
}
```

my-component.html

```
<table *ngIf="data">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
      <td>{{row.column}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<div *ngIf="! data">Loading ...</div>
```

Here are the links for other users coming to this thread for the first time:

- [AngularFire2 setup notes](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md)
- [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)

**Update**

I believe from out dialog in the comments for your original question, the problem lies in the fact that

```
this.display = this.route.snapshot.data['Auth'];
```

is an asynchronous process, and consequently you get subscriptions to both halves of the if else branch.

Your need a **RouterDataResolver** and move the if/else block into it.
See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892392/router-data-resolver-loading-indicator-from-angular-4-can-it-be-replicated-in), that will give you a roadmap for how to proceed.

Comment: i tried logging it but it never goes there thanks anyways