# Expression wrapping in Angular/Typescript: Need explanation of Rule of thumb for when/where it's required

Tags: angular, typescript, tuples, angular2-routing

In this code, can someone explain the rule of thumb for, why/when there is a need for, what I believe is called, *expression wrapping* within Typescript?
i.e. the '(' ')' in **<[Parent, (Children[])]>**.

1. If I defined a tuple type for example and used that in the resolve implements/method signature of the main code, would you still need the '(' ')' wrapped around the array of Children?
2. Are there other scenarios in Typescript/Angular where '*expression wrapping*' occurs too?
3. Is the specific to Angular? For example the '?' *type safe navigator* I found out about is an Angular embellishment to Typescript, not yet part of the language. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247362/replacement-of-elvis-operator-of-angular2-in-typescript/39247628#comment77332604_39247628) and [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

---

```
type parentChildTuple = [Parent, Children[] ]
```

- versus

```
type parentChildTuple = [Parent, (Children[]) ]
```

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataComponentResolver implements Resolve<[Parent, (Children[])]> {

    constructor() {

    }

    resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<[Parent, (Children[])]> {



    }
}
```

Comment: -- i got down vote but i have no idea why? `For example the '?' type safe navigator I found out about is an Angular embellishment to Typescript` -  it's not there in typescript or angular.

Comment: 1) https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax  and 2) https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators 3) https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: It's in angular template code only, not in typescript.

Comment: Ok.. get your point Template syntax - vs... Typescript.. Will cross out that part.

Answer (score -1):

1. What you say about expression wrapping is just for making the code clearer. Not have any effect.
2. It's the same when you say: if (a > b && c < d) -> if ((a > b) && (c < d))
3. Angular2 (typescript) uses typescript.  `'?' type safe navigator` is not there for angular nor typescript. Everything in typescript will be there in Angular and vice versa.

Comment: I suspect you got a down-vote, because, if you had followed the links for point 3 you would see that was an incorrect statement.  From what I can tell () is a necessity for the Tuple definition as defined in the Resolve signature.